Oracle APEX cards region - reverse cards layout from right to left
I have two cards regions in one line. Both regions display cards from left to right. For the first region, it's good. But in the second case it starts in the middle of the row and doesn't look good. Is it possible to revers cards only in the second region from right to left? Both regions are not related.
current:
|CARD A||CARD B||CARD C||...||...|   |CARD A||CARD B||CARD C||CARD D||...|
purpose:
|CARD A||CARD B||CARD C||...||...|   |...||CARD D||CARD C||CARD B||CARD A|
--APEX 24.1--

This can be achieved with a bit of css. Example on the sample data EMP table.
Create a cards region on the emp table and duplicate it. The first region shows left to right (the default) and the 2nd region should show rigth to left.
In the page attribute "CSS > Inline", I put the following:
.dir_rtl {
  direction:rtl;
}

On the 2nd cards region, set that css class:

Result:

Notes:
You might want to reverse the ORDER BY for the 2nd region since if you only care about the layout but want the order left to right.
